# ReactPhp deploying on Ubunutu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, reactphp

Hi I have working REST Api with ReactPHP on my local machine
I want to deploy it on a dev server ,

I added a newsubdomain on DO, placed a conf with nginx, setup a ongoing process to php index.php my server root file for ReactPHP app.

Allowed the port 8000.

Now I am unable to access my api routes 
My server log says `Listening on tls://127.0.0.1:8000` as default echo on `$loop->run();`

on hitting the route of subdomain it says

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>

</html>
```

My nginx conf

```
server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com;
    root /var/www/api; 
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host  $host;
        proxy_read_timeout     60;
        proxy_connect_timeout  60;
        proxy_redirect         off;

        # Allow the use of websockets
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    } 


    listen 443 ssl http2; 
    #ssl info removed
}
```

Comment: `listen 80;` looks wrong to me. try `listen 8000;`

Comment: You are creating a HTTPS server in ReactPHP, but your Nginx reverse proxy accesses HTTP. Since you have a Nginx reverse proxy, you do not need a HTTPS ReactPHP server. A simple HTTP server is enough. Create a `TcpServer` instead of a `SecureServer`.

Comment: Is this still an open issue?

Comment: Now deployed and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some error and trials made it working

```
server { 
listen 80;
server_name test.example.com; 

location / {
    proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host  $host;
    proxy_read_timeout     60;
    proxy_connect_timeout  60;
    proxy_redirect         off;

    # Allow the use of websockets
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
} 

location /favicon.ico { alias /path/to/favicon.ico; }

listen 443 ssl http2; 
#ssl info removed
```

}

Some points

- Remove root from server
- Remove index {We dont need one because ReactPhp has its own Server}
- Match proxy_pass port with your ReactPhp Server port
- Its better to provide SSL via proxy with nginx { as ReactPhp Docs}
- 502 Bad Gateway { It was happening because my server was not running at that moment}